# Parsing URL parameters with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I've a url similat to example.com/?id[]=15029&id[]=18711&foo=bar#MyTab

I want to get all the id's in the url

```
var str = window.location.search;
var result = {};
str.replace(/([^?=&]+)(?:[&#]|=([^&#]*))/g, function (match, key, value) {
    result[key] = value || 1;
});
result;
```

Above code only returns the last id paramenter.

How can I improve it to get all ids in an array?

Comment: why regular expression? `split('&').forEach`, and done.

Comment: see how my regular expression handles `#`'s

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values) post.

Comment: @Mithun `location.search` doesn't include `location.hash` at all.

Comment: @Mike Corcoran None the answers there handles `[]` case

Comment: what are the `[]` there in the first place for? is that some obscure syntax for shoving arrays in query strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it

```
function getUrlParam (paramName) {
    var str = window.location.search;
    var result = {};
    str.replace(/([^?=&]+)(?:[&#]|=([^&#]*))/g, function (match, key, value) {
        if (key.indexOf("[]") !== -1) {
            key = key.replace(/\[\]$/, "");
            if(!(result[key])) {
                result[key] = new Array();
            }
            result[key].push(value);
        } else {
            result[key] = value || 1;
        }
    });

    if(result[paramName]){
        return result[paramName];
    } else {
        return '';
    }
};
getUrlParam('id')
```